# JQuery TableSorter Resizeable Widget not working

Tags: jquery, widget, tablesorter, resizable

I've been struggling for a while to get the resizable widget working with jQuery Tablesorter, but no joy. On http://www.1point5degrees.com/p/uks-sustainable-fleet.html for the bottom/main table, one can click on the table header cells to sort (so the main tablesorter function works), but there's no way to resize the widths of the cells.  I'm aware the css is in a muddle too, but not sure if that's the root cause of the problem, or if it's something else.

Thanks in advance,

Richard.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you not simply style the `<td>` elements? Like `td { width: 20% }` or similar? It would be helpful if you could update your question so that it shows all relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem that hasn't worked, and why you think it hasn't worked :)

Comment: Could you post the tablesorter code and related html?

Comment: <script crossorigin="anonymous" integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA=" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>

<script charset="utf-8" src="https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/js/jquery.tablesorter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: <script> 
$(document).ready(function() 
      { 
        $('#myTable').tablesorter({sortList: [[3,0],[0,0]],widgets: ['zebra']} ); 
      
      } 
    );

</script>

<script src="https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js" type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
    $('#myTable').tablesorter(
    {
    widgets: ['zebra', 'resizable' ],
    widgetOptions: 
        {
         resizable: true
        }
    }
);

});
</script>

Comment: <table class="tablesorter" id="myTable" style="width: auto;">

<thead>
<tr><th>Man.</th><th>Model</th><th>Power</th><th>CO<sub>2</sub></th><th>PIG</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>BMW</td>
<td><a href="http://www.bmw.co.uk/en_GB/new-vehicles/bmw-i/i3/2013/start.html" target="_blank">i3</a></td>
<td>Electricity</td>
<td>0</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">1</td>
</tr>

Comment: @lindon have pasted some code above, but it doesn't format well.  All the relevant code is on the single page in the original link, so you can 'view source' of that - it's just a Google-hosted blog site (blogger)

Comment: Works on this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f2q100/8vwpbhr0/). Difficult to debug using the the page source since a lot of what shows there has been added by tablesorter. Need to know what the raw code is to really be able to help. When posting code here, would surround with tick marks as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).

Comment: @lindon thanks so much for your efforts - you helped narrow down what wasn't the problem, and I've now simplified the .css, and things have started working fine.  Not *exactly* sure what was wrong to be honest, but got there in the end. Thanks!